# Normalise the columns of a dataframe (sum equal to 1)

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have the following dataframe df containing weights:

```
df <- as.data.frame(t(matrix(seq(1,9), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)))
> df

  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
2  4  5  6
3  7  8  9
```

I would like to produce a new dataframe df_2 with normalised weights (sum of the columns must be equal to 1) as below:

```
> df_2

   V1         V2          V3
1  0.1666667  0.3333333   0.5
2  0.2666667  0.3333333   0.4
3  0.2916667  0.3333333   0.375
```

Note that the way I normalise a vector w is the following:

```
w_normalised <- w/sum(w)
```

Comment: `df/apply(df, 1, sum)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to divide with rowwise sum of the dataset

```
df/rowSums(df)
```