# Elementwise division between a data frame and a vector

Tags: r, dataframe

In a very elegant answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51177271/normalise-the-columns-of-a-dataframe-sum-equal-to-1), akrun showed that one can normalize a data frame of numbers row-wise with very little work:

```
df <- as.data.frame(t(matrix(seq(1,9), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)))

  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
2  4  5  6
3  7  8  9

df / rowSums(df)

         V1        V2    V3
1 0.1666667 0.3333333 0.500
2 0.2666667 0.3333333 0.400
3 0.2916667 0.3333333 0.375
```

My question is, simply, why does this work the way that it does? My understanding of R data frames is that they are special cases of lists, and I would not expect matrix operations to work automatically. I would at least expect column-wise operations to be prioritized (i.e., I would expect the division operation above to divide each *column* by each element of the `rowSums` vector).

Comment: It is just due to recycling.  Here the first element of 'V1' column is divided by first element of `rowSums`, then goes to the second element and so on.  Once the first column is completed, the same recycling starts for the next column

Comment: D'oh. It's been a while since element recycling has mattered to me. Still, I find it a little strange that R is willing to proceed with element-wise division in a data structure that is, internally, several separate objects.

Comment: From trying this on a slightly bigger dataset, efficiency is negligible `set.seed(24);df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(5000 * 5000), 5000, 5000)); system.time(df1/rowSums(df1)); system.time(df1/rep(rowSums(df1), nrow(df1)))`